# How to resolve generic conditional type using the AST in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, typescript-generics, conditional-types

I would like to know the real type of a variable which is typed with a Generic type by using the TypeScript AST. I am able to do it for simple cases, like this one :

**Example :**

Here is the code written by the user :

```
type FooType<T> = T extends string ? string : number;
let fooVar: FooType<string>;
```

I would like to "read" this code by using the AST and find that the real type of `fooVar` is `string`.

For this example, I can do it. For that, I use the wonderful library `ts-morph`.

At first, I find the type of first order of `fooVar`, which is `FooType<string>`.
(for simplicity, I wrote the code of the user in the same file than mine)

```
import { Project, SourceFile, TypeAliasDeclarationStructure } from 'ts-morph';


type FooType<T> = T extends string ? string : number;
let fooVar: FooType<string>;

function getFirstOrderType(varName: string): string {
    return sourceFile.getVariableDeclaration(varName).getStructure().type as string;
}

const project = new Project();
const sourceFile: SourceFile = project.addSourceFileAtPath(__filename);
const firstOrderType: string = getFirstOrderType('fooVar');
console.log(firstOrderType); // ----> FooType<string>
```

Now, with this information, I will read `FooType<T>`, replace `T` by `string`, solve the predicate `T extends string` and return the true case : `string`.

```
type Ternary = [predicate: string, trueCase: string, falseCase: string];

function resolveGenericType(genericType: string): string {
    const typeName: string = genericType.split('<')[0];
    const typeParameter: string = genericType.match(/<.+>/g)[0].slice(1, -1);
    const fooTypeStructure: TypeAliasDeclarationStructure = sourceFile.getTypeAlias(typeName).getStructure();
    const [predicate, trueCase, falseCase]: Ternary = (fooTypeStructure.type as string).split(/[?:]/g) as Ternary;
    return predicateResult(typeParameter, predicate) ? trueCase : falseCase;
}


function predicateResult(typeParameter: string, predicate: string): boolean {
    const typeToExtend: string = predicate.split(' extends ')[1].trim();
    if (typeParameter === typeToExtend) {
        return true;
    } else {
        // TODO
    }
}

function getType(varName: string): string {
    return resolveGenericType(getFirstOrderType(varName))
}

const resolvedType: string = getType('fooVar'); // ---> = 'string'
```

OK, that's perfect, my method `getType()`returns `string`.

Now, I want to be able to solve the non-trivial cases, like this one :

```
type BarTypeParent = string;
type BarType<T> = T extends BarTypeParent ? string : number;
let barVar: BarType<string>;

const resolvedBarType: string = getType('barVar'); // ---> TODO
```

In other words, I want to be able to check if a type extends another one with the AST.

Any idea will be appreciated !!! :)